# Something under ladyfinger leaves

Tags: okra

What are these small sugar crystal like thing under my ladyfingers leaves?

[image: Okr]

Comment: Can you update your post with your location?  Could it be aphids?  Are the thinks moving if you touch them?

Comment: Location is Kolkatat, India. No they don't move.

Answer (score 2):

These are calcium oxalate crystals formed by fluids released by the leaf pores, and then drying out to form crystals. They will probably drop off in time.

That they are on the undersurface of the leaf distinguishes them from psyllid sugar crystals which I see on the uppermost part of the leaf in susceptible plants of which okra is not.